# Osc. offset circuit, adjustable precision shunt regulator

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, pcb-design, altium, circuit-design

I want to design this old amplifier again. My question is about TL431CLP adjustable precision shunt regulator. I want to simulate that on LTspice to make sure it is working fine to have a report.

Is there any alternative in the software for this component or any equivalent for oscillator offset circuit?

[image: Amolifier circuit]

Answer (score 0):

The TL431 is one of the most jellybean of jellybean ICs. Chances are if you check the bottoms of your shoes after walking through [Huaqiangbei](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huaqiangbei#/media/File:Huaqiangbei_walking_street.jpg), one or more will be stuck on there. Digikey has over 200,000 available in SOT-23 in just [one type](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Nexperia/TL431_Family.pdf) (NXP). LCSC has hundreds of thousands in various types.

A majority of inexpensive wall wart power supplies probably have one on the output for feedback. The TL431CLP is TI's version, but compatible versions are made by many other companies starting at under a penny depending on tolerance, brand name etc…

So, there is no need to substitute for this part other than changing the suffix perhaps for another manufacturer, tolerance or package (but that, even, is unnecessary).

(in answer to the changed question)

As far as LTspice, if it's not in your existing libraries you can [download](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kFL8c5-FQcs) a model for it, or download an entire library that contains it. Check out [Bordodynov](http://bordodynov.ltwiki.org/)'s fine work, for example.

Comment: Thanks, i restate my question.